# Fetch data from database into table with angular 2

Tags: angular

i want to fetch data from my database and display in a data table. When i run my app, i see on the network tab that the response has been fetched but i does not display in the table. Here is my code;

// Client.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpService} from "./Client_Service";
import {Response} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'client',
  templateUrl:'client_table.html',
  providers:[HttpService]
})

export class ClientComponent implements  OnInit{
  welcome: string;

  Clients: [{
     first_name:string,
     last_name: string,
     email: string,
     company_name: string,
     mobile: string,
     city: string,
     website:string
  }];
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService){
    this.Clients = {
      first_name:"",
      last_name: '',
      email: '',
      mobile: '',
      company_name: ' ',
      city: '',
      website:'.'
    }[];
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.httpService.getCustomer()
     .subscribe(
       (data: any) =>{
         console.log(data.json());
         this.Clients = data
       })
  }
}
```

//Http service

```
import {ClientComponent} from  './Clients'
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Response, Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';




@Injectable()
export class HttpService{
  constructor(private http:Http){}

  getCustomer(){
         //using get request
         return this.http.get('http://localhost:9000/api/crm_api/v1/customers')
         .map((response:Response) => response.json());
  }
}
```

//Html table

```
<h1>{{welcome}}</h1>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Website</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let client of Clients; let i = index">
    <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{client.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{client.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{client.email}}</td>
    <td>{{client.mobile}}</td>
    <td>{{client.company_name}}</td>
    <td>{{client.city}}</td>
    <td>{{client.website}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

//stack trace

```
ClientComponent/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:33304:25
SafeSubscriber</SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:632:13
SafeSubscriber</SafeSubscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:581:17
Subscriber</Subscriber.prototype._next@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:534:9
Subscriber</Subscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:498:13
MapSubscriber</MapSubscriber.prototype._next@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:10596:9
Subscriber</Subscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:498:13
XHRConnection/this.response</onLoad@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:46041:21
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:101091:21
NgZone</NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:30795:28
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:101090:21
Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:100980:28
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:101161:28
```

[Api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewFdB.png)

Comment: you log `console.log(data.json());` but assign  `this.Clients = data` shouldn't it supposed to be the json version again?

Comment: @echonax, i am not really clear with your statement but if i am right, i already set the Json version to the line  this.Clients = data and still same results

Comment: I'm saying that try to set it to `this.Clients = data.json()`

Comment: @echonax, I just tried that. the table is still empty

Comment: But the log is correct right? then try to put safe navigation operator(?) inside your html like this: `<td>{{client?.first_name}}</td>`

Comment: @echonax     That didn't work either and i get the above stack trace

Comment: Can you update your service code so it's actually what you have because looking at that wouldn't even work you don't even have the correct imports being imported.

Comment: @JJB correcting the imports neither solved my issue please

Comment: Can you correct this in your question code or it will be hard for people to solve.

Comment: @JJB , edited. i am sure there is a silly error somewhere. Been at this for days

Comment: Ok you don't need to import the component into your service so remove import {ClientComponent}... also you are returning data.json() and then calling that again in your console which is basically doing data.json().json() just console the data variable. Once you've done that check if you have the data in your console

Comment: @JJB, i see the response fetched from the database  when i go the network tab in the console

Comment: Yes that's the http part but do you see the console.log in In the console tab?

Comment: @JJB,  i don't see console.log but i see a an original stack trace error and a typeerror saying data.json is not a fucntion

Comment: Did you change it to console.log(data);

Comment: Now, I see an array of objects like this  Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object ]

Comment: @JJB, thanks so so so much for this. It's showing up in the table now after i assigned this.Client = data... thanks a lot

Comment: Ok that's good :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `Clients` as below inside your component :

```
Clients: {
  first_name:string,
  last_name: string,
  email: string,
  company_name: string,
  mobile: string,
  city: string,
  website:string
}[];
```

Comment: @ranakrnal9 , nothing happened!

Comment: share your response which you are getting from API .

Comment: I just posted a shot of the Api respone. I tried to copy it but wasn't not working so i sent the screen shot

Answer (score 0):

You need to import [rxjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs) into your project.